# Does this code pass a value to var?

Tags: java, android

There following code is from https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/webserver/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/SimpleWebServer.java.

Does the code `static {mimeTypes(); ...}` pass value to the var LICENCE?  Is this valid java syntax? When will the var LICENCE  be passed value? Runtime or Compile-time ?

```
/**
 * The distribution licence
 */
private static final String LICENCE;
static {
    mimeTypes();
    String text;
    try {
        InputStream stream = SimpleWebServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/LICENSE.txt");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = stream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            bytes.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        text = bytes.toString("UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        text = "unknown";
    }
    LICENCE = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `static {` is a static initializer block. This code is run once when the class is loaded.

`LICENSE` is set to the value of `text`, which is obtained from the `bytes.toString()`.

It will be set at Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Of cause it will pass value to the var `LICENCE`. This block will be executed just one time once that class is loaded.

But, `DO NOT` coding like this. Reading/Writing must not be invoked in `Main Thread` to not get `ANR`.